# Updating multiple documents in mongodb using _id field

Tags: mongodb

I have sample products table and would like to update multiple documents using _id field. Every time, I try this it only updates the first doc in the $in clause I mentioned , not updating all.

```
db.products.update({_id:{$in:[ObjectId("507d95d5719dbef170f15bff"),
ObjectId("507d95d5719dbef170f15c01"), ObjectId("507d95d5719dbef170f15c00")]}},
{$set:{'monthly_price':7865}}, {multi:true})
```

Comment: this query works for me. you have some other problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can first try running find on the products table to make sure that all the object ids actually exist.

You can also try [explain command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/)

Answer (score 0):

give this a try:

```
db.<collection>.update( { query }, {$set: {monthly_price:7865}}, false, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the object id's which you have given doesn't exist in the collection.
I tried using the following query and it worked for me.

```
db.test.update({_id:{$in:[ObjectId("57b33483e5b9ce24f4910855"),
                          ObjectId("57b33483e5b9ce24f4910856"),
                          ObjectId("57b33489e5b9ce24f4910857"),
                          ObjectId("57b33491e5b9ce24f4910858")
                         ]
                     }
                 },
                 {$set{'isCurrentStatus':true}}, 
                 {multi:true}
              )
```

[image: Query result]

Comment: Hi sai teja, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Rather than including a screenshot of the result of your query, your answer would be better if you pasted it in as text. That way it is more readable and indexable etc. On this site, users are encouraged to make edits to improve their answers as much as possible, so that would be a good start.